# How to get the file names in a specific folder and concatenate the file name with some characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i'm trying to write a batch file script which will create a .sql file and write the content i want, following is the logic i'm trying,  We need to consolidate all the .sql scripts for each country and create a master .sql files which will call all other .sql files, we will provide these files to our DBA team, they will run the master files instead of running the individual files,

I have created the script which will create the .sql file and few basic commands with @echo commands also i'm able to list the files in a specific folder but i'm not able to do a loop to concatenate the file names with few characters at prefix and suffix.

following is the code i tried

```
    @echo off
        break>"C:\Gopi_Kishan\DBBR\Daily_attachments\ausqascript_20190708\dblank.sql"

    cd C:\Gopi_Kishan\DBBR\Daily_attachments\ausqascript_20190708

    @echo Set scan off;>>dblank.sql
    @echo alter session set current_schema="SV2AUPR";>>dblank.sql

    rem dir /b "C:\Gopi_Kishan\DBBR\Daily_attachments\ausqascript_20190708\" >>dblank.sql
```

i would like to output to be in following way

```
Set scan off;
alter session set current_schema="SV2AUPR";

@@BLUE-CR616-APPLICATION_NO_CHANGE.sql;
SHOW ERROR;

@@CR_deployment_script.sql;
SHOW ERROR;

@@Addroledetails.sql;
SHOW ERROR;

@@SV2_IBIS_MOVE_DATA_PR_ALL_DB.sql;
SHOW ERROR;
```

i want to add '@@' infront of the file name and ';' at the end of the file name 
can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(
@for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b "C:\Gopi_Kishan\DBBR\Daily_attachments\ausqascript_20190708\*.sql"') do @echo @@%%a;&@echo show_error;
)>>dblank.sql
```

should do what you appear to be asking. The parentheses surrounding the `for` command allow the output to be redirected by the `>>` (append to file).

For ... `*.sql` (each `.sql` file) get its name in basic form to `%%a`. `/a-d` means no directoryname matches. Then `echo` this with its prefix and suffix followed by the `show_error;` line; redirected to append to the file.

Note that the `@` preceding each batch command is not rrequired if you execute `@echo off` as is normal at the start of the script.

Comment: @KishanM - When there is an answer that works for you, please select the check mark to indicate to others that the answer is correct. This is how SO works.